# npm WARN trumbowyg@2.21.0 requires a peer of jQuery@>=1.8 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, npm, trumbowyg

npm WARN trumbowyg@2.21.0 requires a peer of jQuery@>=1.8 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.

When i run anything on npm, it gives me above error. How do i solve this error?

Answer (score -1):

In the package file of the package, search for 'jQuery' and change it to 'jquery'.

Comment: Hi, Its already 'jquery' at the package file. I even tried to reinstall jquery. Still gives me same error.